# Can I change the radio frequency according to my encryption algorithm?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, decryption

I know that information can be changed by changing the frequency of electromagnetic vibrations.My question is, can I change the frequency according to my encryption algorithm? That way I can get a frequency that doesn't match anywhere. This would increase the reliability of my algorithm.
cable radiates. Can I algorithmically change the electromagnetic radiation emitted by a cable of the same material?

Comment: "This would increase the reliability of my algorithm." - we've been reading this asking about a method to secure radio transmissions.  Are you asking about something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is actually "yes", but it's generally not done due to encryption, it's done for the practicalities of RF.    When you change frequencies, you often change the channel saturation for information.  There's at least one commercial application that uses AES-128 after an ecc25519 exchange when for a 60GHz channel when you have power enough to run the oscillator (80Mbs channel) and then uses the same key for SIMON128/128 for a coherent clock case (100kBs channel), which is powered passively when the power is off for the larger system.

Although not what you'd call encryption, but obfuscation, synchronized chaotic oscillators are used for analog feeds, and sometimes other "eyes only" items because the brain can remove the signal from the noise. Those circuits will use a different LC tank based on the the frequency of the carrier because you need to use the carrier as a "sync" signal for the best outcome.  If you are part of the IEEE, look for a paper from MWSCAS from between 2008 and 2010 by the US Army.  That's the best implementation that I've seen from a tutorial perspective.

Answer (score 16):

More physical layer security than encryption. Spread spectrum wideband radio using frequency hopping does this.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum

What is required is a hard-to-predict sequence of frequencies. This can be generated using an encryption mechanism. The [Spread spectrum communications handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070576297) book is the classic reference. There is also code division spread spectrum but you want *frequency hopping*.